# How to detect outgoing call in android to a specific number?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-intent

We can easily detect whether is user on a call or not. I need to add a filter i.e. Did user make any call to a specific number. Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe you can checkout my code [here](https://github.com/xdtianyu/CallerInfo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/xdty/callerinfo/receiver/IncomingCall.java#L46)

Answer (score 0):

Create a BroadcastReceiver class and register it inside manifest file. And check the outgoing call intent.

Ex:

```
public class DialCallListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String OUTGOING_CALL_INTENT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";

//Inside onReceive method, check the call state
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int callState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    try {
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

      //Check if call state is OFFHook
      if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            callState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;

            //Call the listener interface when call state change. And handle this state change inside PhoneListener class.
    MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener(context);
    PhoneListener.onCallStateChanged(callState, number);
      }

     }catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}
}

//Now create a listener if call state changed (on dialing any number)

```
private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener implements ICallReceiver {


public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String dialing_number) {

         switch (state) {
         case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                //Handle Call dial
                mPresenter.handleCallOffHook(incomingNumber);
                break;
         }
```

}
}